# Passing the previosly selected range cells in a spreasheet to VBA focus to work with

Tags: vba, select, range

I want to make a VBA macro to format a group of cells previously selected, but i can not pass the selected range to VBA, can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: what do you mean you `can not pass the selected range to VBA`  Can you share the code in which you tried?

Comment: Can you give any example of your current code and data ?

Comment: For example i select a group of cells, let say "B3:J10" and i need to format all with borders and color, and i want to make it running a macro.

Comment: The use `With Selection` and do the things you want with that selection and finish with `End With`

Comment: Sub Macro2()
    a = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address
End Sub

Comment: The last Active.currentRegion do not work properly, I will trie with your sujection thank Scott

Comment: Can you send me an example?

Comment: Remember the macro do not know the range, it have to be read from the Spreadsheet

Comment: when I use A= Active.cell.address I get the adrress of the selected cell but not the range,                                                                                                                 
when I use A=  ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address I get a range that do not correspond with the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

The first sub will show you the range you have selected, although I do not think you need to know the range (it is already selected) so the bottom two subs should be of more interest to you.

You can make changes to your selection using either method. (`With` block or directly qualified ranges)

```
Sub ShowRange()

MsgBox (Selection.Address(False, False))

End Sub
```

---

Notice that the `With` block will qualify every format with a range

```
Sub Method1()

With Selection
    .Font.Size = 16
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

---

Without the `With` block, you will need to directly qualify each format with a range (`Selection`).

```
Sub Method2()

Selection.Font.Size = 10
Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```